# Javascript utilizing array won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to achieve an effect where one of the 6 text options appear randomly on load/refresh.

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    var myQuotes = new Array();
    myQuotes[0] = "text option 1";
    myQuotes[1] = "text option 2";
    myQuotes[2] = "text option 3";
    myQuotes[3] = "text option 4";
    myQuotes[4] = "text option 5";
    myQuotes[5] = "text option 6";

    var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random()*myQuotes.length);

    $('#myQuote').html(myQuote[myRandom]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried borrowing code from here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-can-i-show-a-different-quote-at-random-on-page-refresh

Comment: what do you mean by won't work ?

Comment: When the script is invoked there exists no _Element_ with _id_ equal to _myQuote_ (`<span id="myQuote">Quote will go here</span>`). This means `$('#myQuote')` finds no _Elements_ and thus `.html(foo)` has no effect. Furthermore, it would be cleaner to write your _Array_ as a literal, `['A', 'B', 'C']`

Comment: @PaulS. Quite likely. And if this is really the whole HTML page, then not even jQuery is included.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: @Thilo also true, I got ahead of myself because the problem with this kind of code is nearly always invocation before element exists..

Comment: Guessing this was a typo...need an 's' on .html(myQuotes[myRandom]); also I see no html element with id="myQuote"

Answer (score 0):

`$('#myQuote').html(myQuote[myRandom]);` 
change to 
`$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);`
The script should put at the end of `body` for the ready of `myQuote`. And I suggest you to use the debug module of your browser. You will find things went wrong when the code execute at the last line.

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential problems.

**First**, your `myRandom` variable may exceed the maximum index (5) of your `myQuotes` array. The length of `myQuotes` == 6; therefore, your formula below will return a value between 0 and **6** which will lead to an out of bounds error.

```
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * myQuotes.length);
```

Instead, use `myQuotes.length - 1` like so (of course this *assumes* that your array is greater than zero, so do some length checking):

```
var myRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (myQuotes.length - 1));
```

**Second**, as pointed out by others, you are referring to a **myQuote** variable instead of **myQuotes**.

```
// You have:
$('#myQuote').html(myQuote[myRandom]);

// How about:
$('#myQuote').html(myQuotes[myRandom]);
```